# How to add text on surfaces of cubes

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d, plot-annotations

How to add text on surfaces of cubes. I'm trying to solve 3d packing problem but i have problem visualization because if there were 1000 cubes, how to identify each of them.So i need to write number on surfaces(every surfaces if it is possible).

output that i dont want:

[image: output that i dont want]

output that i need:

[image: output that i need]

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How to add text to a surface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23814753/7758804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [`text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.text) to 3D-Axes specifying the position and direction. The following example puts the text on the center of the frontal x-z face of each box:

```
xz_sizes = np.array(sizes)
xz_sizes[:,1] = 0
label_pos = (np.array(positions) + xz_sizes / 2).tolist()

labels = ['12', '24']
for pos, label in zip(label_pos, labels):
    ax.text( *pos, label, 'x', ha='center', va='center')
```

[image]

PS: if you like you can directly calculate `label_pos` as a one-liner but for me this seems to be more convoluted than using the auxiliary array `xz_sizes`:

```
label_pos = (np.array(positions) + np.insert(np.array(sizes)[:, [0,2]], 1, 0, axis=1) / 2).tolist()
```

---

**Update**: putting the labels on all surfaces works exactly the same way: the following examples show it for two other surfaces (1 x front, 1 x back), so I guess you get the idea:

```
label_pos_y = (np.array(positions) + np.insert(np.array(sizes)[:, [0,2]] / 2, 1, 0, axis=1)).tolist()
label_pos_x = (np.array(positions) + np.insert(np.array(sizes)[:, [1,2]] / 2, 0, 0, axis=1)).tolist()
label_pos_z = (np.array(positions) + np.insert(np.array(sizes)[:, [0,1]] / 2, 2, np.array(sizes)[:,2], axis=1)).tolist()

labels = ['12', '24']
for pos_y, pos_x, pos_z, label in zip(label_pos_y, label_pos_x, label_pos_z, labels):
    ax.text( *pos_y, label, 'x', ha='center', va='center')
    ax.text( *pos_x, label, 'y', ha='center', va='center')
    ax.text( *pos_z, label, 'x', ha='center', va='center')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks how can i add same text on every surface? @Stef

Comment: Have you got.an idea for keep them still?

Comment: I don't think you can keep them still (i.e. glued to the surface, no matter how you rotate the surface in space). It might be possible using pyvista [`box`](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/utilities/_autosummary/pyvista.Box.html?highlight=box#pyvista.Box)es, write the number on a surface and apply this surface as a texture, see [this example](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/02-plot/texture.html), but I guess it also requires a lot of fiddling to get it right.

Comment: please help my new question. new question connected with this question.